# Matplotlib histogram y-axis range

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to draw a histogram, I store the data-set as a dictionary; the keys of the dictionary are the x-axis of the hist and the values of the dictionary are the y-axis. The dataset is shown below; however, I meet a problem that the difference in the dictionary is huge; how could I how the small value in the hist and why the max range in the axis is 3.0, I want it to be 120,000 or something can represent the value in the dictionary. The code and the hist are[image] shown below. The code is shown below. Thanks in advance!

```
buyCount = dict(buyTemp['time','count'])
buyBins = list(buyCount.keys())


plt.hist(buyCount.values(),bins = buyBins, align = 'left',stacked = True, histtype = 'bar', rwidth = 0.5) #,density = True)
plt.xlabel('Broker Id', fontsize = 14)
plt.ylabel('Frequency', fontsize = 14)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.title('Times for buy activities', fontsize = 14)
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of posting images, copy paste your original code. It is more helpful than images!

Comment: Did you consider using a [log scale](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html) for the y-axis?  A [broken axis](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html) is also a possibility, though much more complex.

Comment: log scale is not working, the graph keeps unchanged. And the code has added.